# I am making a pong game and I want pymunk to detect what object it touched last

Tags: pygame, collision, pymunk

I am making a pong game with powerups using pygame and pymunk and was I want the powerup to go to the last person who touched the ball what code can I use to accomplish this Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To give you an insight of how it could look like conceptually:

```py
player_list = [player1, player2, player3, player4, player5]

for player in player_list:
    if player.touch_ball():
        player.has_power()
        break
```

Try implementing this in your code, the for loop could sit somewhere inside the main game loop.

Also, you have to provide [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).